# MySQL: Show A.id and B.id where no relation is met

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I have the following Tables:

```
Table A
id | name
1  | foo
2  | bar

Table B
id | name | default
1  | 123  | 1
2  | 321  | 0
3  | 456  | 1

Table C
A_id | B_id
1    | 2
1    | 3
```

now I would like to get the A-B pairs (with condition that these pairs have B.default = 1) which are not in C

So the expected result would be:

```
A_id | B_id
1    | 1
2    | 1
2    | 3
```

but I'm totally confused about how to join table B in:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id
FROM A

LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON C.A_id = A.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN B
AND C.B_id = B.id
AND B.default = 1
```

Comment: you can't get it the way you want: what if you have 2 rows from A not in C and 5 rows from B not in C? Unless you want all A-B pairs not in C. In which case, the required data is wrong: you are missing A=1, B= 1 from the A-B pairs (1,1), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3)

Comment: In your expected result how are a_id and B_id related? if they are not in C?   Are are you looking for the aggregation of all Values of A  with A, where b.default =1 and A is not in C? So so if a had rows with id 1,2,3,4,5 you would would a_id, b_id tuples lik 2,1 2,3 3,1 3,3 4,1 4,3 5,1 5,3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all A-pairs first, then compare to C

The NOT EXISTS is slightly more correct (anti-semi-join) than a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
    X.A_id, X.B_id
FROM
    (
    SELECT
      A.id AS A_id,
      B.id AS B_id
    FROM
      A CROSS JOIN B
    WHERE
      B.default = 1
    ) X
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
      FROM
         C
      WHERE
         C.A_id = X.A_id
         AND
         C.B_id = X.B_id)
```

However, this gives this result. Only the C tuple of (1,3) matches the 4 A-B pairs

```
A_id | B_id
1    | 1
2    | 1
2    | 3
```